# IsNothing error

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have the following error which I can't understand from my expression.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value),"6mr",LEFT(Format(DateValue(MonthName(Right(Fields!month.Value, 2))
 + "," + 
 Left(Fields!month.Value,4)), "Y"),3) + " '" + RIGHT(Format(DateValue(MonthName(Right(Fields!month.Value, 2))
 + "," + 
 Left(Fields!month.Value,4)), "Y"),2))
```

This works perfectly without the IsNothing element.

I have tested the IsNothing element and that works in the following case:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value),"6mr",0).
```

Help to correct much appreciated.

Comment: what does the month.value field look like before ? what is expected to look like? It seems you might have an extra ' in + " '" +

Comment: you probably need to test the `else` expression separately. see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing this "issue" because Reporting Services evaluates both sides of the `Iif`.

This is not really an issue, it is by design, see this technet article for more details:

- [SSRS - IIF function evaluates both True & False](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11840.ssrs-iif-function-evaluates-both-true-false.aspx)

> Yes , By design the SSRS evaluates both True & False statements even
>   though the condition is not satisfied and through error if something
>   is not right.

Now, to get your expression working, you have to consider that `Fields!month.Value` could be nothing even in the false part of your expression.

So in your expression, you could just replace

```
Fields!month.Value
```

by

```
Iif(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value), "1", Fields!month.Value)
```

Here is an expression with this fix:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value),"6mr",Left(Format(DateValue(MonthName(Right(Iif(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value), "1", Fields!month.Value), 2))
 + "," + 
 Left(Iif(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value), "1", Fields!month.Value),4)), "Y"),3) + " '" + Right(Format(DateValue(MonthName(Right(Iif(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value), "1", Fields!month.Value), 2))
 + "," + 
 Left(Iif(IsNothing(Fields!month.Value), "1", Fields!month.Value),4)), "Y"),2))
```

You could also create a custom function or use a variable if you want to reduce the expression length.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien that works perfectly. Thanks for the in-depth answer.