# SSRS Why is this relatively simple IIF statement returning an intermittent error?

Tags: reporting-services

I have one table that holds all data.  This table includes unique ID field ("ID").   I have another table that records when each record from the first table is processed.   This table has a field ("ID") in which the unique ID from the is inserted when the record is processed.  The second field here is the timestamp for when the record was processed.

In my report I list all of the records in the first table for the last 24 hours.  I include a final textbox on the end of the row, which is labeled "Transferred?", and should have a value of either "Yes" or "No".

The formula I am using to calculate the last field is:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!UTC_PROCESSED_DATE.Value, "TransferredData")), "No", "Yes")
```

I compare the ID fields in both tables and if the ID of the current record is not in the 2nd table, the output is "No", and if it does exist the output is "Yes".

Generally this works fine.   However, I am having intermittent issues when the first record in the list has a value of "#Error".

**Why is this relatively simple IIF statement returning an error?**

Additional information:  This does not seem to be limited to the top row, as I've seen one result after a refresh, the record previously on top had the Error message still had the error.  Another refresh and that record was fine, and the top again had an Error.   The Error does not always show up, but is very common.

---

Related, but not duplicate question: [IsNothing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250706/isnothing-error)

- The True/False answers are strings rather than calculated values that attempt to access non-existing records.

Comment: I created a sample report with 2 datasets and the same IIf statement you used. I have about 100 rows and refreshed several times. I'm not able to replicate the issue. Even if either column has NULL values, it's still not throwing any errors. Is there anything else you've added to the report that could potentially be affecting this?

Comment: Have you ran the report in the VS Preview and checked the Error List? Usually it will give a vague clue as to what the issue is. Are the **ID** data types the same?